# What role does caste play in modern day Hinduism?

Tags: caste-system

For the past times, one may argue in support of caste system as in support of categorization and classification of people, but disregarding social and political issues, does it hold any use today in the spiritual sense?

Comment: In the texts, it plays the prime role. Caste (varnashrama) is the foundation of Hinduism. However, in the present times (over the last millennium or so perhaps), this caste has become a vanity parade for the upper caste (UC) to subjugate the lower ones notwithstanding that the UCs themselves aren't following not a single guidelines prescribed for them,atleast most of the UC's aren't. In the present times, it has become reduced to being namesake with ego for one's birth. Noone is following 'the dharma' as per scriptural definitions.

Comment: In continuation with the thread , one may wonder how far this shloka from shrimad Bhagavatham is relatable in modern times  ekAdashaskandhaH-
saptadhashoAdhyaya-

brahmanasya hi deho ’yam
ksudra-kamaya nesyate
krcchraya tapase ceha
pretyananta-sukhaya ca